# angle formulae simplication

Tags: trigonometry

I have a question on simplication with the angle formula. My textbook has the following equation.

$\sin(x+\pi) = \sin x\cos\pi + \cos x\sin\pi$

From there, it gives the next iteration as:

$ = (\sin x)(-1) + (\cos x)(0)$

I don't know how it got there, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the cosine and sine of $\pi$?  You probably know the shape of the cosine curve and the sine curve.

Comment: Ok, i see it now. I was using degrees instead of radians.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is because $\cos{\pi}=-1$ and $\sin{\pi}=0$

To see why this true use the formulas:

- $\sin{2A}=2\sin{A}\cos{A}$ and
- $\cos{2A}=2\cos^2{A}-1$

when $A=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: The double angle formulas are derived from the sum of angle formulas.  The sine and cosine of $\pi$ can be determined directly from the unit circle.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thanks for the info.I thought an alternative answer might be useful, even though I admit it's a overkill. Should I delete this answer in the best interest of the O.P? I await your advice.